# Can I write a Go method that operates on a struct with arbitrary number of fields?

Tags: go

I have a Go struct that looks like this:

```
type myStruct struct {
    A bool
    B bool
    C bool
}
```

I want to write a method that flips the bool values from `true` to `false` and vice-versa. But I don't want to repeat the same code 3 times for fields `A`, `B` & `C`. I want to write a loop.

I'm thinking something like this:

```
func (m *myStruct) flipBools() {
    r := reflect.ValueOf(*m)
    for i := 0; i < r.NumField(); i++ {
        // WHAT GOES HERE?
    }
}
```

But I don't know what to put inside the loop. Can it be done? I realize this is a tall order for a strongly typed language like Go.

Comment: It is highly inefficient compared to the obvious alternative. The reflect-based code is shorter to write, but you'll need comments that explain what is being done there. The obvious alternative is hard to write, but won't need any comments to explain, and it'll run faster.

Answer (score 3):

No need for reflection.

```golang
func (m *myStruct) flipBools() {
    ps := []*bool{&m.A, &m.B, &m.C}
    for _, p := range ps {
        *p = !*p
    }
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/RrCo4Kph-hl

---

You can even extract the logic into a variadic func and have it be re-used, if you want to:

```golang
func flipBools(ps ...*bool) {
    for _, p := range ps {
        *p = !*p
    }
}

func (m *myStruct) flipBools() {
    flipBools(&m.A, &m.B, &m.C)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/082lu4-VZ18

Answer (score 3):

In the spirit of actually answering the question: yes, it's possible (even if it's not particularly wise). This works:

```
func (m *myStruct) flipBools() {
    r := reflect.ValueOf(m).Elem()
    for i := 0; i < r.NumField(); i++ {
        fld := r.Field(i)
        if fld.Kind() == reflect.Bool {
            fld.SetBool(!fld.Bool())
        } // optional: else, do something else?
    }
}
```

The inner loop is actually pretty easy; the only thing that needed fixing was that using `reflect.ValueOf(*m)` leaves you with an un-addressable value that can't have its fields set; `reflect.ValueOf(m).Elem()` accesses the struct through the pointer, which works fine.